# Connect to docker service name from host machine

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-network

Let's say I have 2 services defined in my `docker-compose.yml` like that

```
# Service app
app:
  networks: 
    - backend
 # Service server
server:
  networks:
    - backend
  ports:
    - 80:80
```

The `app` service will upload data on the `server` service by requesting `http://server:80/` and it will display the data url `http://server:80/data`

Now from my browser I want to click that link but I can't access the `server` via it's docker hostname, I can only access it via `http://localhost:80/data`.

Is there anyway to configure my `docker-compose` to map the hostname `server` outside of docker so it's accessible from my host machine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You will have to update your hosts file `/etc/hosts` (`C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows) with an entry similar to below:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost server
```